# UINavigationController, wrong back animation orientation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, orientation, transition

I have a really weird problem, driving me crazy!

My app has only one orientation: portrait. By pushing a button you can open a `UINavigationController` modally (by calling the method `presentModalViewController`...). This `UINavigationController` can be orientated (`shouldAutorotate` always returns `YES`).

That works fine except for one thing! The transition: it is always in portrait. I don't understand why. I tried to set the status bar's orientation to match the `UINavigationController's` orientation but it didn't work. I m very puzzled...

Can anybody help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code on .m of that view controller where you r presenting modal**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

    if((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```